# Spring Batch CommandLineJobRunner : Error : ClassNotFound

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm getting following error while executing command ( *running on windows OS* ):

> java -cp "build/libs/BatchExample.jar;lib/*"
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner
>   JobConfigClass jobName

**Error:**

Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner

My project is a gradle project.

I tried many options but no luck.

Please help.

Note: 
BatchExample.jar already have spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar inside BOOT-INF\lib\

Comment: If you are using gradle, then run _bootRun_ task

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried this, getting error with datasource bean initialization because it can't read application.yml file. Error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: required key [env.db.driver] not found

Comment: It seems that you don't have database driver in the classpath. Can you paste content of your _application.yml_  file?

Comment: env:
  db:
    driver: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
    username: something
    password: something

After futher debugging, I realized that environment bean doesnt hold applicationYml configurations, because of which getRequiredProperties is throwing exception.